# Play framewor 2.5 runMain from command line

Tags: java, playframework-2.5

```
package batch;

import models.*;

import play.*;
import play.inject.guice.*;

class ImportData
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().in(Mode.TEST).build();
    AuthorizedUser user = AuthorizedUser.findByUserName("some.user.name"); 
    System.out.println("Hello World!" + user.userName);
  }
}
```

Hi, 
I use Play framework 2.5, and I have a problem to run main function.
I want to run a main function from command line for crontab.

```
bin/activator "runMain batch.TestBatch"
```

I run the code and this code above shows "Hello World!" with string from database, but console stops after execution.
I do not know what the problem is. Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to run `main` method.

Create the new project from a template.

`$ activator new my-first-app play-scala`

Run play.

`$ activator run`

More dails in the documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/NewApplication